# xperf profile services

Tags: windows, performance, process, services, xperf

When I profile using xperf there are always cases when I see, that, say svhost(1552) "eating resources". I could then go to ProcessExplorer and see that svhost(1552) running like 10 services.

How to determine which of the services is a culprit?
Is it possible to configure xperf somehow to see the statistics for each service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the threads of the process, this will allow you to pinpoint the service itself.

Comment: But sometimes it is hard to say, which thread belongs to which service. Is it possible to definitely know, what service this thread belongs to?

Comment: @MajesticRa: The image name (a EXE, DLL or SYS file) should be enough to pinpoint the service, the stack of a thread lists which function of which images are being called...